# How to share VirtualBox Windows XP Guest's Internet Connection with Ubuntu 13.10 Host?

Tags: networking, windows, virtualbox, internet

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 with Windows XP SP3 Installed as a Virtual Machine, the only way for me to access the internet is using a PPP broadband USB Modem (DWM-156) I am not able to run it in Ubuntu, I managed to install it on XP and get it to work but I don't know how to share that connection with Ubuntu. I googled it and not found any working workaround for me. I tried all types of "Attached to:" settings on my guest OS, but no success (perhaps there is more settings that I did not).

I'm not an expert, so please explain your answer in step-by-step approach.

Could someone shows me an easy way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: This is not a duplicate of my question too: [How to share Guest's internet with host on Virtualbox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/337500/how-to-share-guests-internet-with-host-on-virtualbox) This question is similar to but not duplicate of mine, because it asks about Windows 7 guest, my question is about Windows XP guest. Also this question has only **one old not useful** answer.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of my question: [How to share internet access between Ubuntu and Windows guests OS in VirtualBox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64837/how-to-share-internet-access-between-ubuntu-and-windows-guests-os-in-virtualbox) This question asks about sharing internet connection between two guests on [VirtualBOX](http://www.virtualbox.com), but my question is about sharing internet connection of a guest with a host.

Answer (score 1):

### First Step

- Select your guest virtual machine in the VirtualBox Manager then
  click on **Settings**.
- Select the **Network** category
- Select "Bridged Adapter" in the "Attached to" drop-down list.
- Boot your VM normally

[image]

### Second Step

This [post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=34623#p155000) should help you too:

> Add a NIC to the VM if you haven't attached one already and set it to
>   Host-Only. In the general VB settings, DISABLE the DHCP service for
>   the host-only interface and configure it with the following IP, the
>   last number can be anything between 2 and 254: IP: 192.168.0.2 Mask:
>   255.255.255.0
>
> That is everything you can configure there, but your Host needs a
>   gateway too, and that will be 192.168.0.1. DNS servers can be whatever
>   the Host gets, but you can also use the OpenDNS servers.
>
> In the Guest, right click on the interface that provides internet and
>   click on Properties. Go to the Advanced tab and share the connection.
>   This should set the other interface with the IP of 192.168.0.1 and
>   enable a DHCP server on it. It's a bit of a shame that it can't be set
>   on the Host side to use DHCP, but you can do that manually. Using the
>   DHCP option means that the above steps to set a static IP are not
>   needed, they will be overwritten by DHCP. You have to run the dhcp
>   client from a terminal in order to get the complete configuration for
>   use on the Host.
>
> Hope it makes sense.

Comment: This answer do not solve my problem. Also I am confused: In the first step you say that setting the network "attached to" as "Bridge Adapter" and in second step you say that setting it as "Host-Only"!!! Also I tried both settings and no internet connection in Host!