# ubuntu 16 in VM does not have access to internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm trying to setup ubuntu 64 bit VM on my stupid windows 7 machine.

### The Network information that the Windows is connecting to

[image]

[image]

Wireless LAN adapter IPv4 of the **host machine** - `10.11.209.93`

Ethernet adapter **VB Host-Only IPv4** - `192.168.56.1`

I enabled virtualization in BIOS settings.

### windows Host only configs

[image]

And, I also set the VirtualMachine network provider to be `Bridge Adaptor`.

Also, have network sharing [which is not needed actually]

[image]

[image]

But, there's no connection in the ubuntu VM.

### ifconfig

```
    enp0s3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:2D:32:3E:39:3B
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::48:817c:1b4d:e85a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:1990 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:169 errors:8 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7409 (7.4 KB)  TX bytes:16785 (16.7 KB)

    lo   Link encap:Local Loopback  
         inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
         inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
         UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
         RX packets:50121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:50121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
         RX bytes:17079(7.4 KB)  TX bytes:16785(17.0 KB)
```

### resolv.conf

```
$ cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head                   

    # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) 
    #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
    nameserver 127.0.0.1
    search shaharma.net
```

`ping google.com` just hangs on ubuntu VM.

I tried adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` too but does not work either.

### Refs

[How to share internet access between Ubuntu and Windows guests OS in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/a/64848/37643)

[12.04 on VirtualBox -No internet access on Guest OS](https://askubuntu.com/a/248308/37643)

[How-to: VirtualBox Networking Part Two - NAT and Bridged](http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-virtualbox-networking-part-two.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resolv.conf looks wrong. The DNS server **can't** be 8.8.8.8.4.4.4.4. Somewhere you entered a list of DNS servers, but you forgot the comma between the server addresses *(ie: 8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4)*. Probably did it in the connection script for your network connection. Go to the network icon in the top panel, and choose `Edit Connections...`. Locate and edit the network connection and add the comma, and restart your VM.

update: Your VM settings should include Bridged Adapter. Internet Connection Sharing should be off. Your enterprise network may give you trouble too... if so, talk to your network administrator for more help.

Let us know how you do. Cheers, Al

Comment: sorry that was my STUPID typo. Can you please check that. It's killing me, as I'm trying to work on linux machine, but its taking forever to fix it.

Comment: What is the IP address of your host machine? In the VM, can you ping 8.8.8.8? Can you ping www.ebay.com? Turn off Internet Sharing. **Don't** edit resolv.conf. Cheers, Al

Comment: ps: In Windows, do you connect to the Internet via ethernet, or wireless? Cheers, Al

Comment: Wireless LAN adaptor IP of the host machine - 10.11.209.93 and I'm connecting to internet in host machine via Wireless.

Comment: Somewhat strange IP. Do you have a wireless router/modem supplied by the Internet provider, or did you supply your own wireless router? You didn't answer the ping questions. The IP of the VM should be something like 10.11.209.nnn. Change the bridge setting back to original eth0, **reboot** VM, note the IP address with ifconfig, and try Internet again. Turn Internet Connection Sharing off. Let me know. Cheers, Al

Comment: `ping google.com` just keeps hanging. This is some corporate WiFi, for which I dont have access to the router.

Comment: Make the changes that I suggested, and report back. Do you have other machines that connect to the Internet wirelessly? Cheers, Al

Comment: Yep, m making the changes. Hopefully that works. I also added info regarding the network I'm using.

Comment: Remember I said **Don't** manually edit the resolv.conf file? Also, these comments are getting long, and they may push us out to a chat room, but the link will be here. Cheers, Al

Comment: so, removed network sharing in windows config, changed VM network adapter to NAT. But enp0s3 has the same inet addr.

Comment: What I think is the network is not shared for some reason.

Comment: I didn't say change to NAT. Set it back to bridged. I said change the device from your wireless card back to eth0. Cheers, Al

Comment: Damn, so I changed my network to different one and it works. I have Bridge Adapter, but no sharing connection config in windows. The same VM with strange IP is working. You can update your answer, I would mark it as answer. THANKS, but I have no idea how I'm gonna make it work with that stupid internet connection

Comment: Done! Cheers, Al